# CloudFoundry get DopplerEndpoint from V3 Api

Tags: cloud-foundry

In the CloudFoundry V2 Api it was possible by calling an info endpoint to retrieve the DopplerEndpoint.

```
/v2/info
```

What is the equivalent call in the V3 api, or did this feature get dropped / is missing ?